# Save document with tuples

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, export-to-csv

I have a dataset containing multiple columns and each column contains tuple data. I want to save this data so that I can recall it in different python notebooks without having to rerun everything again. Any format is okay (csv, JSON, etc.).

| id | pos_tag | clean data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [(sangat, RB), (baik, JJ)] | [baik] |
| 2 | [(sangat, RB), (membantu, VB)] | [membantu] |
| 3 | [(kenapa, WH), (kok, NN), (perbaikan, NN), (sistem, NN), (bayar, VB), (bisa, MD)] | [perbaikan, sistem, bayar] |

This is what I found so far...

```
df.to_pickle('test.pkl')
new_df = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')
```

Will also need help on how to recall the data.

Comment: why do you want to save it to a csv?

Comment: any format is okay. the issue is that I want to recall my dataset without having to re-run the codes. @Amir

Comment: writing to pickle doesn't work for you?

Comment: for me writing to pickle works!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want write data to csv and retrieve it back, I have an example for you:

```
# Sample dataframe written to csv file and read back
d = {'id': [1, 2], 'pos_tag': [(1, 2), ("a", "b", "c")]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1.to_csv("/content/df1.csv", sep="|", index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv("/content/df1.csv", sep="|", )
df2.head()
```

I save it to csv with a pipe delimiter, just to make sure it is different from other literals like comma, semicolon etc.

```
# Retrieve tuple values
df2['pos_tag'] = [eval(s) for s in df2['pos_tag']] 
df2.head()
```

[image]